# if "or pipes" (||) bug?

Tags: if-statement, pipeline

I'm looping through my `view`'s `subviews` (with a total of **10** subviews).

Before doing so, I declare a new `int` to be used as a counter.

I'm checking if the count isn't equal to a hard-coded value (`!=`):

```
int count = 0;

for (UIView *subview in self.view.subviews) {
    count = count + 1;

    if (count != 5) {
        NSLog(@"Hello");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"World");
    }
}
```

With this, `NSLog(@"World");` is invoked when the count is equal to "5" (as expected):

`Hello
    Hello
    Hello
    Hello
    World
    Hello
    Hello
    Hello
    Hello
    Hello
    Hello
    Hello`

Now to the issue, if I add "or pipes" (`||`), `NSLog(@"World");` is never invoked (`if` isn't validated).

```
int count = 0;

for (UIView *subview in self.view.subviews) {
    count = count + 1;

    if (count != 5 || count != 6) {
        NSLog(@"Hello");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"World");
    }
}
```

`Hello
     Hello
     Hello
     Hello
     Hello
     Hello
     Hello
     Hello
     Hello
     Hello
     Hello
     Hello`

Now this issue can ofc be fixed by changing the syntax, but my question is why isn't the `if` validated?

It should be noted, that changing the "not equal" (`!=`) to "is equal" (`==`) solves the issue.

Is this a bug, or have I missed something?

Comment: It is always the case that `count` is either not equal to 5 or not equal to 6. It could be one or the other, but it can't be both at the same time. You've made your conditional expression always true.

Comment: @KenThomases But i'm checking if it's 5 or 6 using the pipelines (`||`). If I where to check if it was both, I would have used `&&`.
Also, "changing the "not equal" (`!=`) to "is equal" (`==`) solves the issue."

Comment: @AleksanderAzizi this is a case of [De Morgan's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your conditional is always true. Given `count != 5 || count != 6`, if `count == 5` then the latter half is true; if `count == 6` then the former half is true; and if count equals anything else, the statement is also true.

You may have meant to use `&&` instead.